# Getting Error "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.assign" when tring to consume using flink's Kafka Consumer

Tags: java, maven, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I was trying to write a Kafka Consumer which consumes data from a topic. But whenever i try to run it i get the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$6.apply$mcV$sp(JobManager.scala:897)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$6.apply(JobManager.scala:840)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$6.apply(JobManager.scala:840)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:39)
at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:415)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.assign(Ljava/util/List;)V
at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internal.KafkaConsumerCallBridge.assignPartitions(KafkaConsumerCallBridge.java:39)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internal.KafkaConsumerThread.reassignPartitions(KafkaConsumerThread.java:391)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internal.KafkaConsumerThread.run(KafkaConsumerThread.java:229)
```

The Java Class is:

```
import org.apache.flink.api.java.utils.ParameterTool;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer09;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.SimpleStringSchema;


public class KafkaConsumer {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    ParameterTool parameterTool = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args);

    DataStream<String> stream = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer09<String>("rdf-new", new SimpleStringSchema(), parameterTool.getProperties()));

    stream.print();
    env.execute();
}}
```

I had created a standalone project (with its own pom) in intellij with the same code and it was working fine but since i required the code in another project i created a new maven module in the already existing project and then tried running it and now it is showing me this error.

The dependencies in the pom.xml for the maven module is:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <flink.version>1.4.2</flink.version>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <scala.binary.version>2.11</scala.binary.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-clients_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-core</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka-0.9_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-cep_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The only thing i noticed was inside the maven module i was getting the KafkaVersion as 1.1.0, but the pom has the KafkaConnector "flink-connector-kafka-0.9_2.11"

```
2018-05-18 11:14:56,105 - AbstractConfig                           [WARN] - ConsumerConfig            - The configuration 'zookeeper.connect' was supplied but isn't a known config. 
2018-05-18 11:14:56,105 - AppInfoParser$AppInfo                    [INFO] - AppInfoParser             - Kafka version : 1.1.0                              
2018-05-18 11:14:56,105 - AppInfoParser$AppInfo                    [INFO] - AppInfoParser             - Kafka commitId : fdcf75ea326b8e07
```

While in the standalone project (where the consumer properly works) the Kafka Version is 0.9.0.1.

```
11:32:19,537 WARN  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig              - The configuration zookeeper.connect = localhost:2181 was supplied but isn't a known config.
11:32:19,537 INFO  org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser                   - Kafka version : 0.9.0.1
11:32:19,538 INFO  org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser                   - Kafka commitId : 23c69d62a0cabf06
```

It would be a huge help if someone can tell me what could be the issue? It could be because of dependencies in the pom file but in the standalone project also its the same dependencies that i had given in. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you already figured out the problem is that in your module the kafka version (1.0) doesn't match the version that flink connector is expecting (0.9).

You can do:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

on the command line to figure out where the kafka clients dependency version is coming from.

In your module's pom you can add a dependencyManagement section to override the kafka client library dependency version to the one you need, like so:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: Thanks Michal. Adding the dependency Management worked.